# C# Terminar un programa en cualquier momento pulsando ESC

Tags: c#

Tengo que crear el siguiente programa.

> Escribe un programa para jugar a adivinar números.
>
> El programa tiene que seguir los siguientes pasos:
>
> 1.Calcular de forma aleatoria el número que el jugador debe adivinar. El número debe hallarse  entre 0 y 50 (ambos inclusive).
>
> 2.Preguntar números al jugador contestando si son mayores o menores que el número a adivinar.
>
> 3.Si el jugador acierta el número, la partida terminará indicando la cantidad de tentativas hechas por este jugador para acertar.
>
> 4.Habrá un máximo de tentativas dependiendo del nivel elegido para jugar: (fácil =10,medio = 6, difícil = 4).
>
> 5.El programa preguntará si se desea seguir jugando. Si se responde que sí el juego seguirá pidiendo un nuevo nivel y generando otro
>   número.
>
> 6.Para salir habrá que pulsar ESC.

Actualmente tengo un código ya escrito que cumple los 5 primeros puntos, pero tengo problemas con el último, ya que tiene que cumplirse en cualquier momento del programa. Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Modulos
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool NumeroAcertado(int numeroAAdivinar, int numero, out string mensaje)
        {
            bool acierto = numero == numeroAAdivinar;
            if (acierto)
                mensaje = $"Enhorabuena! Has acertado.";
            else if (numero > numeroAAdivinar)
                mensaje = $"El numero a adivinar es menor.";
            else
                mensaje = $"El numero a adivinar es mayor.";

            return acierto;
        }
        static void Juego(int numeroAAdivinar, int oportunidades)
        {
            bool acertado = false;
            int intentos = 1;
            while (acertado == false && intentos <= oportunidades)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Introduce un número entre 0 y 50");
                int numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                acertado = NumeroAcertado(numeroAAdivinar, numero, out string mensaje);
                mensaje += $" Intentos: {intentos}";
                Console.WriteLine(mensaje);
                intentos++;
            }
            if (intentos > oportunidades && acertado == false)
                Console.WriteLine("Te has quedado sin oportunidades");
        }
        static int Dificultad()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
            int oportunidades;

            Console.WriteLine("Elige nivel de dificultad, siendo 1 Fácil, 2 Normal y 3 Difícil, por defecto Normal");
            keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (keyInfo.KeyChar)
            {
                case '1':
                    oportunidades = 10;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    oportunidades = 6;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    oportunidades = 4;
                    break;

                default:
                    oportunidades = 6;
                    break;
            }

            return oportunidades;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            string respuestaUsuario;
            do
            {
                Random seed = new Random();
                int numeroAAdivinar = seed.Next(0, 51);

                int oportunidades = Dificultad();
                Juego(numeroAAdivinar, oportunidades);

                Console.WriteLine("¿Quieres seguir jugando?");
                respuestaUsuario = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            }
            while (respuestaUsuario == "SI");

        }
    }
}
```

El mayor problema que tengo ahora mismo es en puntos donde pida un dato por consola. Ejemplo:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce un número entre 0 y 50");
    int numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

¿Cómo detecto ahí el ESC? Teniendo en cuenta que si uso ReadKey solo detectará un número y no 2 en caso de querer añadir, por ejemplo, 37.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: tienes el código aquí https://repl.it/@batichico/C-C-Sharp

Answer (score 4):

Una solución sería usar `ReadKey` e ir añadiendo los caracteres pulsados a una variable de tipo `string`. He hecho un pequeño método que recoge todo lo introducido por teclado en la consola y lo devuelve. Si se pulsa <kbd>ESC</kbd>, devuelve el string `"ESC"`:

```
static string ConsoleRead()
{
    string entrada = "";
    ConsoleKeyInfo tecla = Console.ReadKey();
    while (tecla.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape && tecla.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (!Char.IsControl(tecla.KeyChar))
        {
            entrada += tecla.KeyChar;
        }
        tecla = Console.ReadKey();
    }

    if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        return ("ESC");
    }
    else
    {
        return (entrada);
    }
}
```

Comment: no se si eres tu pero ni tan siquiewra ha dado tiempo a leer la nueva publicación que he hecho y le dan dislike, dejo el codigo aquí paso que me hateen por hatear. https://repl.it/@batichico/C-C-Sharp

Comment: @Batichico Los votos son secretos en el sitio y te recomiendo que no te los tomes como algo personal, suelen ser en casi todos los casos por el contenido. De todas maneras, ya que dejas el enlace, permiteme decirte que no se si se ajusta a lo que pedía el op, dado que no puedes pulsar esc en cualquier momento, solo después de haber introducido algun dato

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias ^^